# Transaction roll back not working in Play Framework with Promises?

Tags: spring, playframework, transactions, playframework-2.0, promise

I try to cover my code with Junit tests and  face really unexpected situation:

**Preconditions:**

`ProductRepository` is classic `Spring Data` implementation, that extends `JpaRepository`.

`ProductService` is service that uses `ProductRepository` inside via `Play! Framework` `Promise`. All `ProductService` methods return `Promise<ServiceResponse>`.

See Junit tests below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes ={SomeConfig.class})
public class ProductTest{

@Inject
private ProductService service;

@Inject
private ProductRepository repository;

@BeforeTransaction
public void beforeTransaction(){
Product p = repository.getProductById(1L);
System.out.println("Before: "+ p.isActive());
}
@AfterTransaction
public void afterTransaction(){
Product p = repository.getProductById(1L);
System.out.println("After: "+ p.isActive());
}
@Test
@Transactional
public void checkProductRepository(){
Product p = repository.getProductById(1L);
p.setActive(1); 
repository.save(p);
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void checkProductService(){
service.activateById(1L).get(1000L);
}
}
```

**Result:**

*Before: **0** 
 Began transaction for .. checkProductRepository.... 
 Rolled back transaction for... checkProductRepository... 
 After: **0***

*Before: **0** 
 Began transaction for .. checkProductService.... 
 Rolled back transaction for... checkProductService... 
 After: **1***

But how it is possible?!
For second test, where I use `ProductService` transaction rolled back, but it didn't reverted status `active` for `Product` (**After: 1**).

Can anybody explain: How it is possible? And how to resolve this issue.